# Center elements in a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm making a website for a design class and I'm having a hard time placing things like I would want them to be.

I would like all box on the same row to be the same height, but I don't want a fixed height because the website will be responsive in the future. I would also like it if I could vertically center the content of the boxes.

Here is a screenshot of what it should look like: 
[image: Desired result]

And this is what it actually look like:
[image: Desired result]

I tried many things but I can't think of a nice way to do that.

Here is a link to my current code: http://cgagnier.ca/gived/design/

Thank you very much

Comment: Check this: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/

Comment: what if you set an `height` css attribute to every div?

Comment: `.grille_6{min-height: 245px;}` should fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your two figures in **flex box div**

```
<div style="
        display: flex;
    "><figure class="grille_6">
                <img alt="DLC" src="img/p_dlc.png">
                <figcaption>
                    <h1>Tous les DLC gratuits</h1>
                    <p>Obtenez gratuitement tous les DLC de Bugfield. Vous pourrez profiter de tous ces nouveaux bug une semaine en avance!</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>

            <figure class="grille_6">
                <img alt="Mallette" src="img/p_mallette.png">
                <figcaption>
                    <h1>Participation au banquier™</h1>
                    <p>Lorsque vous achetez le Premium™, vous êtes automatiquement inscrit pour faire partie des spectateur du Banquier™</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
      </div>
      <div style="
        display: flex;
    ">
            <figure class="grille_6">
                <img alt="Couteau" src="img/p_couteau.png">
                <figcaption>
                    <h1>Nouvelles armes exclusives</h1>
                    <p>Obtenez des nouvelles armes exclusives tel que le couteau bipod qui comprend une lampe tactique et une mire optique x10</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>

            <figure class="grille_6">
                <img alt="Priorité réduite" src="img/p_serveur.png">
                <figcaption>
                    <h1>Priorité en file réduite</h1>
                    <p>Lorsque vous rejoindrez un serveur, vous serez placé dans une file spéciale à priorité réduite. Tous les autres joueurs passeront avant vous.</p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue:

```
#premium figure {min-height: 203px;}
```

It is mobile responsive.

Another solution will be to use a `<table>` layout, but in my opinion, stick to the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

For equal heights columns you can also take a look here (use of pseudo elements):

http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/

Or another way is to explore the display:table rule, so you could define boxes as table-cells. This would then probably address also the vertical align problem (just using the vertical-align property on table-cell elements).

--

For the vertical aligning itself, I sometimes take advantage of the inline-block vertical-align property.

So, define every inner block as inline-block and with vertical-align:middle (so they align with each other). Then use a pseudo ghost element with height:100% to align the others with it.

I've also got a sass mixin for that:

```
//to be placed on a pseudo :after/before
@mixin vertical_pivot{
  content:"";
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this last technique is also explained here (see the ghost element part by Michał Czernow):

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify a max-height for those images like so

```
#premium figure img {
    max-width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 149px;
    min-height: 149px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an div arround those div's give it a class, like `container`, and give it a min-height and max-height.

div:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a container and use the 2 columns as table cells. This is a really primitive demonstration, but I hope you've got the point. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2f49f2d/)

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    display: table;
}
#content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #000; 
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #cecece;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br>Sidebar<br></p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Main content</p>
    </div>

</div>
```